# .htaccess with php GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple requirement.

All the .php extension must be removed and my GET request URL

```
http://domain.com/product.php?name=<product_name>
```

should become

```
http://domain.com/product/<product_name>
```

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^home/?$    index.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^product/([A-Za-z]+)/?$    product.php?name=$1    [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

When I do this all the .php & .html extensions are removed but the GET page css and js is breaking

Tried this also:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$    product.php?name=$1    [L]
```

Then the .php extension is shown or it goes to the GET request page.

I am new to .htaccess. Breaking my head with it now!

Comment: Give full URL for js and css in your get page.

Comment: yeah, I am thinking about using *<base href="/">* . This works! But don't know if it's the right thing to do/use!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ## If the request is for a valid directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    ## If the request is for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    ## If the request is for a valid link
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
    ## don't do anything
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # if requested files exists in /public then forward it there
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /public/$1 [L]

    # if requested files doesn't exist in /public then forward it to requested php file
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Tried the first portion of ur code for /public - not working

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /product.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this, it should leave you with the URL: `http://domain.com/product/<product_name>`.

Comment: CSS/JS/img's break!